# Show a new empty Sales Order after creating one

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

My client creates many sales order and it is boring for him to see the sale order he has just created. He would like when he clicks on the save button, to be presented with a new view of sales order (like when he clicks on 'create' button)
I have overridden the function for creation of sales order in my custom module and try to return a new views of sale order.

It does not work, I don't know if is the good way.

Thanks for your help

This is my code :

```py
from openerp.osv import  osv, fields
class sale_order(osv.osv):
    _inherit =  "sale.order"
    def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
        super(sale_order, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context=context)
        return {
            'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
            'view_type': 'form',
            'view_mode': 'form',
            'res_model': 'sale.order',
            'context': context,
            'target': 'new',
        }
```

Comment: When you say it does not work, what actually happens?

Comment: The view come back to main view (inbox view for me) and I have error in log
   `File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/osv/expression.py", line 1261, in __leaf_to_sql
    params = model._columns[left]._symbol_set[1](right)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/openerp/osv/fields.py", line 274, in <lambda>
    _symbol_f = lambda x: int(x or 0)
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'`

Comment: I think what's happening is that there are other functions that make use of the `sale_order`'s `create` function and are expecting the ID to be returned. Since you are overriding the function and returning a dictionary instead, Odoo throws an error.

Comment: Do you know how resolve this situation?

Comment: Not at the moment I don't. However, I can suggest your user to either (1) use shortcut keys - [check out this list](https://www.getopenerp.com/shortcut-keys-to-use-odoo10/) - or to (2) use Odoo's import function to mass import sale orders